# C++ passing variables

Tags: c++

Edit I commented on the fix below. I was defining the class incorrectly.

I'm trying to pass variables through an object to the class. Please forgive me if I'm not using the proper names of, I'm new to c++.
For example I would normally do this:

```
    int variable1 = 1;
    int variable2 = 2;
    parameters.setParameters(variable1,variable2);
```

I would like to pass 1 and 2 directly through like this:

```
    parameters.setParametes(1,2);
```

But this does not get recoginized. I've tried doing this:

```
   parameters.setParameters(variable1 = 1, variable2 = 2)
```

Is there a way I can pass just the variable value without using its name?

This is how the class sees them:

```
  void Example::setParameters(int variable1, int variable2)
```

basically I want to hard-code in the numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: The first syntax should work: `instance.setParameters(1, 2);` What, specifically, goes wrong when you try it?

Comment: Also, you misspelled "parameters" in `parameters.setParametes(1,2);` as "Parametes"

Comment: They somehow get set to zero although I never set them to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it looks like `void Example::setParameters(int variable1, int variable2)`? `void Example::setParameters(int& variable1, int& variable2)` seems to be the code here. Maybe you just 'forgot' `const`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Example{
    public:
        Example(){};
        void setParameters(int ,int);
};
void Example::setParameters(int x, int y)
{
     //...
}
int maim(){
    Example ex;
    int var1 = 1;int var2 = 2;
    ex.setParameters(var1,var2);
}
```

You cannot use keyword parameters in c++. If you want to set optional arguments, you must define another function or use templates.